# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment in iteration

Tags: python

I'm trying to process some data, but when I try to iterate over a dict, I get the error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data_origin = {datetime.strptime('2020-10-23', '%Y-%m-%d'): [77, 77], datetime.strptime('2020-10-22', '%Y-%m-%d'): [85, 84]}
iot = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_origin, orient='index', columns=['shirt', 'shoes']) #index of interest
key_list = ['shirt', 'shoes']
rq = {'shirt': {'top': {'shirts black': 100, 'shirts white': 50}}, 'rising': {'coat': 100, 'trenchcoat': 65}} #related queries
rt = {}
iot2 = {}
data = dict(zip(['key','iot','rq','rt','iot2'],[key_list,iot,rq,rt,iot2]))

iterations = 1

print(type(data))

for i in range(iterations):
    if i==0:
        for t in data:
            t['topic_name']=''
```

what am I getting wrong?

Comment: First of all, where is `topic_name` even written? But if you replace `t['topic_name']=''` with `print(type(t))` you'll see 5 of the 6 `t`'s in `data` are strings, which is why you see the error.

Comment: what is 'topic_name'?

Comment: 'topic_name' is a new value beign initialized. It is part of the code of a legacy function I'm trying to test. I'm trying to figure it out the shape of the 'data' field that is passed to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much on what you are trying to achieve, i can explain the error.

As you define it at line 10, `data` is a dictionary (notice the dict()). When looping over a dictionary in python, you loop over its keys.

So when you loop using `for t in data`, the vairable `t` contains just a key, the data type of which is `str`. On the next line you try to add an item to `t` as if it were a `dict`. But str objects don't support this, hence the error.

If your intention was to loop over the keys and values in the dict `data` you can use `for key, value in data.items():` and then use `value` for further processing.